# How to avoid “Exception: Prelude.head: empty list”? - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Good evening everyone, I'm new to haskell. I'm trying to sum up a list of reading a string Unicode values and store them in a list and then sum the integers up.

```
 getLetterUnicodeValue :: Char -> Int
 getLetterUnicodeValue l = (ord l) - 64

 unicodeValueList :: String -> [Int]
 unicodeValueList x = getLetterUnicodeValue (head x) : unicodeValueList (tail x)

 total :: [Int] -> Int
 total []     = 0
 total x = (head x) + (total (tail x))
```

I got the error of empty list when the string come to the last character and the sum up function cannot successfully execute. Is there any way to stop the function `unicodeValueList` when it comes to its end.

```
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Comment: Yes there is, *and you've already done it for `total`*...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The surest way to avoid this exception is not to use `head`. Instead you can use pattern matching to get the head and tail of a list:

```
unicodeValueList (x:xs) = getLetterUnicodeValue x : unicodeValueList xs

total (x:xs) = x + total xs
```

This way `x` and `xs` will only be available when the list is non-empty and it is guaranteed that you never accidentally access the head or tail of an empty list.

Of course now you'll get a warning that the pattern match is incomplete: You don't specify what should happen when the list is empty. Of course this was true before as well, but now that you use pattern matching the compiler can actually see this and warn you about it (whereas the previous code crashed at runtime without any prior warning).

So what should be done when the list is empty? Well, an empty string contains no unicode values, right? So it should return the empty list when the input is empty:

```
unicodeValueList [] = []
```

---

Of course you don't *need* pattern matching to fix your error. You could just use an `if` to make sure that you only call `head` and `tail` when the list is not empty. But if you do that, the compiler won't be able to verify that your checks are in order. If you use pattern matching  and avoid the unsafe `head` and `tail` functions completely, you'll never be able to accidentally access the head or tail of an empty list and the compiler will warn you if you ever forget to consider that the list might be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you just will have to pattern match in `unicodeValueList`

```
unicodeValueList :: String -> [Int]
unicodeValueList [] = []
unicodeValueList (x:xs) = getLetterUnicodeValue x : unicodeValueList xs
```

Note this could be written more nicely as `unicodeValueList = map getLetterUnicodeValue`. The reason you are getting the error for `head` is that your recursion had no base case - it keeps trying to recurse, even when it has reached the empty list.

Comment: Plus one for suggesting `map`. IMO it's more clear than recursion-based solutions, and point-free to boot.